# How to restore an encrypted SD card backup after factory reset?

Tags: sd-card, encryption

I did a factory reset and then realized that I didn't decrypt my SD Card. I know that the data is probably lost, but I did make a complete copy of the Internal Storage.

Is there a way to copy back to the phone, the encryption key? I also know the password I used to generate the encryption. Where is the encryption key file located?

Edit: I made a copy of Internal Storage folder connecting the Samsung J5 mobile to a PC, but I can't find /data/misc/vold. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Internal Storage is */data/media/0* (therefore */data/\** not included)

Answer (score 2):

The encryption key should be located in `/data/misc/vold`. If you backed up that directory, you should see a `.key` file with a long name inside. Open that file with a hex editor, and copy the 16-bit key. You can decrypt your storage using this command in a Linux distribution:

```
dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize <your device ID, ex:/dev/sdb>` crypt \aes-cbc-essiv:<key you copied> 0 <your device ID again> 0"
```

[Source of the command](http://bestrootandroid.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html?m=1)